# Which Image will be used on iPhone 6 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

I have added @1x, @2x, & @3x images in asset catalog.

@2x will be used in iPhone 4/4s, iPhone 5.

@3x will be used in iPhone 6 Plus.

So in iPhone 6 which image will be used?

Comment: Try it and see! Why ask something that can so easily and quickly be determined by experiment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iPhone 6 uses @2x image assets and not R4 or something else because apple didn't provide suitable APIs for background images!

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 6 - Retina HD 4.7 - (750X1334) - 2x

[image]